# Swift - Does UILabel have a 'labelFor' equivalent?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, accessibility

I'm new to Swift. I want to 'link' my `UILabel` element to my `UITextField` element for accessibility.

In Android, if you have a text input, you can use use the `labelFor` attribute on a label to link the label to the associated element. For instance:

```
<TextView
    android:labelFor="@+id/edit_text"
    android:text="@string/aac_edit_text_about_label" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text" />
```

Similiarly, in HTML, you can use the `for` attribute on a `label` to link it to an `input`. For instance:

```
<label for="message">Message</label>
<input type="text" name="message">
```

Is there a similar attribute to link up `UILabel` and `UITextField` (or similiar fields) in Swift/iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't create a connection between a label and an editation field. Instead, you can add a custom accessibility label directly to the text:

```
let myLabel: UILabel = ...
let muField: UITextInput = ...

muField.accessibilityLabel = myLabel.text
```

See [UIAccessibility](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility) protocol for more information.

You can always subclass `UITextInput` and add support for such a connection.

Answer (score -2):

No. There isn´t such a feature. But you can register an event handler (eg a TapHandler) to the UILabel and perform what ever you want when the event is fired.